# Spring security SessionRegister vs Authentication

Tags: spring, security, authentication, spring-security

I try to determine who is online in my website. I have different menu for not authenticated user than authenticated like this:

```
<div sec:authorize="!hasAuthority('ROLE_USER') || !isAuthenticated()">
        menu for not authenticated 
</div>
<div sec:authorize="hasAuthority('ROLE_USER') && isAuthenticated()">
        menu for authenticated 
</div>
```

My isOnline function looks like this:

```
private boolean isOnline(String username){
    List<Object> principals = sessionRegistry.getAllPrincipals();
    List<String> usersNamesList = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (Object principal: principals) {
        if (principal instanceof UserDetails) {
            usersNamesList.add(((UserDetails) principal).getUsername());
        }
    }
    return usersNamesList.contains(username);
}
```

But somethimes user get menu for authenticated and in the same time function isOnline return false for this user. SessionRegistryImpl is not a good way to find authenticated users? What is the difference? What is the best way to unife both issues?

Comment: If someone is authenticated (ie. isAuthenticated is true) someone is logged in and can be considered online. Basically the sessionregistry contains all active sessions, so not sure why you are adding a `isOnline` method seems to complicate things.

Comment: When i get somebody profile data i want to share his status in profile view too. But when user display his own profile, sometimes i get Offline status, in the same moment user is authenticated.